# validating a solution for N queen problem

Tags: java, recursion

I'm trying to write a function that gets a MxN size board, with a column and a row where a queen is placed. and then I'm suppose to see whether that queen is under threat or not. 
normally I would take that row and check it for any other queens, same for the column and the diagonal using for loops. 
however there's a slight change here, there are also walls on the board which could keep the queens safe even if there's another one in the same row :

```
* * Q X * Q
* * X * * *
* Q X X Q *
Q * X Q Q *
```

where Q is a queen, X is a wall , and * is an empty tile. 
the Queen in the 0,2 position is not threatened even though there's another one in that row.

also the entire board is saved in a 2d array, where queens are given the int value of 1, walls are -1, and blanks are 0.

My idea was to go over the entire row and if there's a queen somewhere then I should look for a wall with another for loop from that position up to the queen I'm looking at . however there's also a second part to it after my queen.

I tried thinking about summing but that didn't quite work either..
anybody have any ideas of how to implement this? 
(if threatened return true; if not threatened return false;)

edit: this is my code

```
`public static boolean isQueenThreatened(int[][] board, int row, int col){
        boolean safe=true; 
        for(int j = 0; j < col & safe ; j++){
            if(board[row][j]==1) {
                for (int i = j+1 ; i<col ; i++ ) {
                        if(board[row][i]!=-1) safe = false;
                }
            }
        }
        for(int j = col+1; j < board[row].length & safe ; j++){
            if(board[row][j]==1) {
                for (int i = j+1 ; i<board[row].length ; i++ ) {
                    if(board[row][i]!=-1) safe = false;
                }
            }

        }
        return safe;
    }`
```

So the function gets a location for the queen (assume it's valid) , then I wanna go over that row up until my queen and after it and see if there are other queens, if there are I wanna check if there are any walls between them to keep my queen safe , obviously mine doesn't work because it will give false if there's anything but a wall between them, and it's enough that there's just one wall , it doesn't have to be all walls.

```
* Q * * X Q' * X Q
```

I've denoted my queen with a ', my code would return false for that example even though it should be true.. and then I have to do the same for the diagonal and the column.. this is where I need help.

Comment: do you have a question?

Comment: yes. if there are any ideas of how to make my idea work?
how to efficiently go over the row and see if the queen is threatened , cause I can't just decide it's safe if there's a wall to its' right because there might be a queen to its' left or no queen at all and no walls, and still it would be safe

Comment: You will be better getting an answer if you show the code that you are trying and where is is going wrong.

Comment: I've added my code

Answer (score 1):

This is a perfect opportunity for working with `Iterator`s.

```
static class Board {
    private final int width;
    private final int height;
    private final int[][] board;
    private static final int EMPTY = 0;
    private static final int WALL = -1;
    private static final int QUEEN = 1;


    public Board(int width, int height) {
        this.width = width;
        this.height = height;
        board = new int[height][width];
    }

    public Board(String[] setup) {
        this(setup[0].length(), setup.length);
        for (int y = 0; y < setup.length; y++) {
            for (int x = 0; x < setup[y].length(); x++) {
                switch (setup[y].charAt(x)) {
                    case '*':
                        board[y][x] = EMPTY;
                        break;
                    case 'X':
                        board[y][x] = WALL;
                        break;
                    case 'Q':
                        board[y][x] = QUEEN;
                        break;
                }
            }
        }
    }

    public Iterator<Integer> walk(int xStart, int yStart, int dx, int dy) {
        return new Iterator<Integer>() {
            int x = xStart;
            int y = yStart;

            @Override
            public boolean hasNext() {
                return x + dx < width && y + dy < height
                        && x + dx >= 0 && y + dy >= 0;
            }

            @Override
            public Integer next() {
                return board[y += dy][x += dx];
            }
        };
    }

    public int get(int x, int y) {
        return board[y][x];
    }
}

enum Direction {
    NORTH(0, -1),
    NORTH_WEST(1, -1),
    WEST(1, 0),
    SOUTH_WEST(1, 1),
    SOUTH(0, 1),
    SOUTH_EAST(-1, 1),
    EAST(-1, 0),
    NORTH_EAST(-1, -1),
    ;
    private final int dx;
    private final int dy;

    Direction(int dx, int dy) {
        this.dx = dx;
        this.dy = dy;
    }
}

public static boolean isQueenThreatened(Board board, int row, int col) {
    for (Direction direction : Direction.values()) {
        walk: for (Iterator<Integer> attack = board.walk(col, row, direction.dx, direction.dy); attack.hasNext(); ) {
            switch (attack.next()) {
                case Board.QUEEN:
                    return true;
                case Board.WALL:
                    break walk;
            }
        }
    }
    return false;
}

private void test() {
    String[] test = new String[]{
            "**QX*Q",
            "**X***",
            "*QXXQ*",
            "Q*XQQ*"
    };
    Board board = new Board(test);
    for (int y = 0; y < board.height; y++) {
        for (int x = 0; x < board.width; x++) {
            if (board.get(x, y) == Board.QUEEN) {
                System.out.println("Queen at position (" + x + "," + y + ") is " + (isQueenThreatened(board, y, x) ? "" : "NOT") + " threatened");
            }
        }

    }
}
```

By the way - your queen at `(0,2)` **IS** threatened by the queen at `(2,4)`.

Answer (score 0):

For a given queen position, you need to iterate over the row, the column, and each diagonal. In each direction, you can follow the same rules:

1. If you hit another queen, you are threatened, return `true`.
2. If you hit a wall, you are safe in that direction, move on to the next check.
3. If you hit the edge of the board, you are safe in that direction, move on to the next check.

```
public static boolean isQueenThreatened(int[][] board, int row, int col) {
    // Go over the row, to the left:
    for (int i = col - 1; i >= 0; --i) {
        int val = board[row][i];
        if (val == 1) {
            return true;
        }
        if (val == -1) {
            break;
        }
    }

    // Same logic for:
    // - Going over the row to the right
    // - Going over the column to the top
    // - Going over the column to the bottom
    // - Going over the top left diagonal
    // - Going over the top right diagonal
    // - Going over the bottom left diagonal
    // - Going over the bottom right diagonal

    // If you reached here, it means that no early return was performed,
    // and the queen is safe
    return false;
}
```

**EDIT:**

To answer the requirement in in the comments, you could add extra `boolean`s for finding a threat of hitting a wall, but TBH, I think the code would look considerably worse:

```
public static boolean isQueenThreatened(int[][] board, int row, int col) {
    boolean threat = false;

    // Go over the row, to the left:
    boolean wall = false;
    for (int i = col - 1; i >= 0 && !threat && !wall; --i) {
        int val = board[row][i];
        if (val == 1) {
            threat = true;
        }
        if (val == -1) {
            wall = true;
        }
    }

    // Go over the row, to the right.
    // Reset the wall variable, as you haven't detected a wall in this direction yet
    // The threat potentially found in the previous loop is still present
    // so if it still exists, the loop will be skipped 
    boolean wall = false;
    for (int i = col + 1; i < board[row].length && !threat && !wall; ++i) {
        int val = board[row][i];
        if (val == 1) {
            threat = true;
        }
        if (val == -1) {
            wall = true;
        }
    }

    // Same logic for:
    // - Going over the column to the top
    // - Going over the column to the bottom
    // - Going over the top left diagonal
    // - Going over the top right diagonal
    // - Going over the bottom left diagonal
    // - Going over the bottom right diagonal

    // If you reached here, it means that no early return was performed,
    // and the queen is safe
    return threat;
}
```

Comment: do you have an idea of how to do that without breaking, and without early return. I mean so that I will return only once at the end of the function.. I am required to do so and that makes it a bit difficult for me.

Comment: @lidorportal I've edited my answer and added it, but TBH, I think that using early returns and breaks makes the code much cleaner in this situation.